# checkstyleのcheckFirstSentenceを無効化できない

Tags: java

NetBeans + Gradle でJavaアプリケーションの開発をしています。
コード解析ツールとしてcheckstyle(6.7)を採用しているのですが、checkFirstSentence（javadocコメントの最初の一文はピリオドで終わらなければならない）を無効にできずに困っています。

checkstyleの設定は次のようにしています。

```
<module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="JavadocStyle">
        <property name="checkFirstSentence" value="false"/>
    </module>
    <!--以下略-->
```

JavadocStyleモジュールの挿入場所が違ったり、プロパティ名が違ったり、値にtrue/false以外の文字列を設定すると、ビルド時にちゃんとその旨を伝えるエラーメッセージが出るので、記述自体は正しいと思うのですが、それにもかかわらずcheckstyleからは`warning: First sentence should be present.`の警告が吐き出されてしまいます。

どのような原因が考えられるでしょうか？
あるいは、原因を調べる手段としては、どんなことが可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決したため、回答を投稿します。
SummaryJavadocCheckモジュールにperiodプロパティ（valueは空文字）を追加することで、無効にできました。

```
<module name="SummaryJavadocCheck">
    <property name="forbiddenSummaryFragments" value="^@return the *|^This method returns |^A [{]@code [a-zA-Z0-9]+[}]( is a )"/>
    <property name="period" value=""/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 1):

`sun_checks.xml`を以下のように一部修正し、

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="JavadocStyle">
            <property name="checkFirstSentence" value="true"/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

以下のようなソースを`ant(<checkstyle config="${user.dir}/sun_checks2.xml")`でチェックすると

```
public class Test {
    /**
     * aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
     * @author aterai
     */
    public Test() {
    }
}
```

```
checkstyle:
[checkstyle] Running Checkstyle 6.7 on 1 files
[checkstyle] C:\tmp\AAA\src\java\example\Test.java:35: 最初の一文はピリオドで終わらなければなりません。

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

と警告が表示されます。

```
    <module name="JavadocStyle">
        <property name="checkFirstSentence" value="false"/>
    </module>
```

のように変更すれば、

```
checkstyle:
[checkstyle] Running Checkstyle 6.7 on 1 files
```

と、警告されません。こちらの環境(`Windows 7 64bit` + `JDK 1.8.0_51`)では正常に動作しているようです。違うところはメッセージが日本語になっているところですが...。

> あるいは、原因を調べる手段としては、どんなことが可能でしょうか？

`NetBeans`を使わずにコンソールから実行してみてはどうでしょうか。